# How to make fields in JS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint Form. Anybody have Java script that makes a field( people picker and date) required? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function PreSaveItem()
{
 return ValidateFields()
}

function ValidateFields()
{
 var datefield = $("select[title='DateField']")[0];
 var txtPpl = $(":div[title='PeoplePicker']")[0];

if(datefield[datefield.selectedIndex].value!=null || datefield[datefield.selectedIndex].value!="" )     {
 if(txtPpl.value.length==0)     {
 alert("Please enter Person or Group");
 txtPpl.focus();
 return false;
 }
 else{
 return true;
 }
}
else{
 alert("Please enter Date");
 datefield.focus();
 return false;
}
}
```